# Correct way to say "when I was young..."

Tags: word-requests

What is the usual way to say something along the lines of "when I was young, petrol was cheap" or "when I was a kid, my family lived in Mexico".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can say:

> - 当我年轻的时候，...
> - 我年轻的时候，...
> - 年轻的时候，...
> - 年轻时，...

In these cases, you are talking about the time when you were a young man (**note**: not a kid nor a teenager). Perhaps you are now in your 40s/50s/60s etc, and you are talking about your 20s/30s.

You could also say:

> - 当我年幼的时候，...
> - 当我还小的时候,...
> - 我年幼的时候，...
> - 我还小的时候，...
> - 我小时候，...
> - 小时候，...

In these cases, you are talking about the time when you were a kid or teenager.

Comment: In spoken Chinese, just say 我小时候.

Comment: Can one use 年幼?

Comment: not sure what the deal is with all the pedanticisms... 小时候 will work just fine.

Comment: @tao ,年幼 is more of written Chinese.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a native speaker but I have seen it as:

> 我小时候...

Comment: 我小时候 means you were younger that 10 years old, more or less.